# Show number of items selected in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UICollectionView to show the images. From that collectionView users can choose multiple images. Right now I am able to change view of selected images by overriding selected variable of UICollectionViewCell.

```
override var selected: Bool {
didSet {
    if self.selected {
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
    } else {
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    }
}
}
```

I put a UILabel at the top of UIImageView of cell to show the count. But I am not able to update the number of selected images. The count should be updated when user deSelect the image. How can i achieve this? It should be similar to Facebook image picker.I do not want to reload collectionView.

Comment: make a modal class which stores the cellIndex which are selected and use that to count and show in label

Comment: You just need the count?
var count = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems().count

Comment: depends on you how to get count. Either create an array that stores all selected item indexes or get the count for selected counts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to update all the counts of each cell without reloading the collectionView.On each selection and diselection i need to update count.

Comment: @sant05 This is doing what you want: https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController

Answer (score 1):

As you clarified in your comments, you want the number in the cell to show the order of the selected image.

Add a **singleton** class to hold an array of selected image IDs. The characteristic of a singleton is that its instance is accessible from everywhere in your app:

```
class ImageSelectionManager {

    /// The singleton instance
    static let instance = ImageSelectionManager()

    /// This is the array that holds the order of selected image IDs
    var selectedImageIds: [String] = []
}
```

In your `UICollectionViewController` implement the following delegate functions:

```
class YourViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // Get the selected cell
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourCell

        // Get the selected image ID
        let imageId = cell.imageId

        // Add ID
        ImageSelectionManager.instance.selectedImageIds.append(imageId)

        // Notify cells that image array has changed
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            "ImageSelectionChangedNotification",
            object: self)
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // Get the deselected cell
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourCell

        // Get the deselected image ID
        let imageId = cell.imageId

        // Remove ID
        ImageSelectionManager.instance.selectedImageIds = ImageSelectionManager.instance.selectedImageIds.filter({ $0 != imageId })

        // Notify cells that image array has changed
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            "ImageSelectionChangedNotification",
            object: self)
    }
}
```

In your `UICollectionViewCell` add an observer to notifications and a function to update the counter label:

```
class YourCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    /// The ID of your image that the cell is showing
    var imageId: String!

    /// The counter label
    var counterLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Start listening to notifications
        registerForNotifications()
    }
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        counterLabel.text = nil
    }

    deinit {
        unregisterFromNotifications()
    }

    func registerForNotifications() {

        // Make the cell listen to changes in the selected images array
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.handleNotification(_:)),
            name: "ImageSelectionChangedNotification",
            object: nil)
    }

    func unregisterFromNotifications() {

        // Stop listening to notifications
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func handleNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        // If the notification is the one we are listening for
        if notification.name == "ImageSelectionChangedNotification" {

            // Execute on main thread because you are changing a UI element
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                // Get the position in the selected images array
                if let position = ImageSelectionManager.instance.selectedImageIds.indexOf({ $0 == self.imageId }) {

                    // Image position was found so set the label text
                    self.counterLabel.text = String(position)

                } else {
                    // Image was not found no remove the label text
                    self.counterLabel.text = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## It works like this:

1. A cell is selected / deselected.
2. The cell's image ID is added / removed from the singleton's array.
3. A notification is sent to the cells.
4. Each cell receives a notification and checks the position of its image ID in the singleton's array.
5. If the image ID has a position in the array, the label text is updated with the position. If the image ID is not found that means the cell is not selected so the label text is removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i need without reloading collectionView.How can I achieve that?

Comment: I tried alternative ways but i can not made it work. When I deselect it should decrease all previously selected counter by 1 without reloading collectionView. Would you mind if you explain in detail? Thank you.

Comment: @sant05 I would not recomment to increment and decrement the counter value but rather calculate the number of selected cells every time a cell is selected or deselected.

Comment: For example: I select 5 images then it will show 1,2,3,4,5 as a counter for each selected images. When i deselect image with label 3 then 4, 5 should be decremented to 3 and 4. How to update those count label without reloading collectionView. I would appreciate if you help me.Thanks

Comment: Thanks man it worked if the images are less in number but if there are more number of images and  when i scrolled to down and up then counterlabel is set to nil and sometime number also changed. i think this is because cell are reused.

Comment: @sant05 You need to add the label in your `prepareForResuse` function in the subclass of your cell. I added an example in the code.

Comment: when we use  counterLabel.text = nil in  prepareForResuse  every counterLabel are removed

Comment: @sant05 The code above is an example to give you an idea of the concept. The problems you are facing now are basic `UICollectionView` issues. I suggest you post your current code into your question so your problem is easier to identify.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a model class to store the selection status and the other attributes.
For example you are populating data for an Image in your collectionView.

```
class MyImage : NSObject {
   var name : String?
   var selectionNumber : Int? // Using for selection update on UI 
  /*other properties below*/

}
```

Now in your Collection View Cell make a MyImage property with hooked didSet

```
var image : MyImage? {
didSet {
   imageView.image = UIImage(named:image.name)
   if image.selectionNumber != nil {
      imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
      lblCount.text = String(selectionNumber + 1)
   }
   else {
      imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
      lblCount.text = ""
   }
}
```

Now In your view controller class or the class where you are implementing collectionView's delegate methods.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(kYour_Cell_ID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell
    let myImage = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
    myImage.selectionNumber = self.selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath)
    cell.image = myImage
    return cell
}
```

Where your dataSource will be the array containing MyImage objects and create an array for storing selected indexPaths.

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let idx = self.selectedIndexes.indexOf(image)
        if (idx != nil) {
            self.selectedIndexes.remove(indexPath.row)
        }
        else
        {
           self.selectedIndexes.append(indexPath.row)
        }
       self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([self.selectedIndexes])
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Umair for your answer but I do not want to reload collectionView.

Comment: Do you have a label that is showing the count on each cell? If this is the case then you will have to reload the collectionView as every visible cell has to be updated with the new count value. But if the label is not in Cell but in your viewController's view then you can simply replace `collectionView.reloadData()` with `self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])` in your ` func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

Comment: I stored selected indexPath in an array called selectedIndex then I tried self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndex])  to reload item. It works in top part of the collectionView items. But when I scroll to the buttom part and tried to select and disselect then it reloads the wrong item. I think this is because of reused cells.

Comment: You do not need to store selected indexPath anywhere. Just update the selected status as given in answer and write `self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])` in your collectionView's didSelect method. Reloading a particular item will call cellForItemAtIndexPath again for that particular cell which will update the selection as per yourImage.selected. To re-use the cell, collectionView call the cellForItemAtIndexPath again and as you have updated the yourImage.selected it will show/hide the selection.

Comment: For example: I select 5 images then it will show 1,2,3,4,5 as a counter for each selected images. When i deselect image with label 3 then 4, 5 should be decremented to 3 and 4. How to update those count label without reloading collectionView. If you have working code please update your answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry I did not noticed this update. Could you explain please what is image in let idx = self.selectedIndexes.indexOf(image)

Comment: let image = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]